# Feign retryable exception error in Docker

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, spring-cloud-feign

I have created 4 services Eureka service, Gateway service, Authentication service and User service. Authentication and User service are routing through gateway service on port 8000 and FeignClient is used to communicate between Auth and User service for creating user and authentication.

My services are running fine on local server but when docker images are created I'm getting a Feign retryable exception error.

docker-compose.yml file

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  mysqldb:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: ./.env
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=bank_app
    ports:
      - 3307:3306
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - main-network
  eureka-service:
    build:
      context: ../code/eureka-service
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: eureka-service
    container_name: eureka-service
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - 8761:8761
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod
      - SPRING_APPLICATION_NAME=eureka-service
    networks:
      - main-network
  gateway-service:
    build:
      context: ../code/gateway-service
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: gateway-service
    container_name: gateway-service
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod
      - SPRING_APPLICATION_NAME=gateway-service
      - SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON={"eureka":{"client":{"serviceUrl":{"defaultZone":"http://eureka-service:8761/eureka"}}}}
    networks:
      - main-network
  authentication-authorization-service:
    build:
      context: ../code/authentication-authorization-service
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: authentication-authorization-service
    container_name: authentication-authorization-service
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod
      - SPRING_APPLICATION_NAME=authentication-authorization-service
      - SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON={"eureka":{"client":{"serviceUrl":{"defaultZone":"http://eureka-service:8761/eureka"}}}}
    networks:
      - main-network
  user-service:
    build:
      context: ../code/user-service
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: user-service
    container_name: user-service
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb
    ports:
      - 3005:3005
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod
      - SPRING_APPLICATION_NAME=user-service
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/bank_app?useSSL=false
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=root
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=123456
      - SPRING_JPA_PROPERTIES_HIBERNATE_DIALECT=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
      - SPRING_JPA_PROPERTIES_DDL_AUTO=update
      - SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON={"eureka":{"client":{"serviceUrl":{"defaultZone":"http://eureka-service:8761/eureka"}}}}    
    networks:
      - main-network
networks:
  main-network:
    external:
      name: $NETWORK_NAME
volumes:
  db:
```

application.properties file for Eureka and Gateway service is as follows

application.properties file for Eureka-service

```
spring.application.name=eureka-service
server.port=8761
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
```

application.properties file for Gateway-service

```
spring.application.name=gateway-service
server.port=8000
security.enable-csrf=false

spring.main.web-application-type=reactive
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true

user-service.path=/api/v1/users/**
user-service.uri=http://localhost:3005

authentication-authorization-service.path=/api/v1/auth/**
authentication-authorization-service.uri=http://localhost:3000

eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone= http://localhost:8761/eureka
eureka.client.instance.preferIpAddress = true
```

The following stack trace is generated

```
2023-02-17 16:22:28 2023-02-17 10:52:28.540  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.m.g.GatewayServiceApplication          : Started GatewayServiceApplication in 236.273 seconds (JVM running for 242.047)
2023-02-17 16:27:12 2023-02-17 10:57:12.251 ERROR 1 --- [or-http-epoll-3] a.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler : [5d73c5ea]  500 Server Error for HTTP POST "/api/v1/auth/signup"
2023-02-17 16:27:12 
2023-02-17 16:27:12 io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:3000
2023-02-17 16:27:12 Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
2023-02-17 16:27:12 Error has been observed at the following site(s):
2023-02-17 16:27:12 *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.web.cors.reactive.CorsWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
2023-02-17 16:27:12 *__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WeightCalculatorWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
2023-02-17 16:27:12 *__checkpoint ⇢ HTTP POST "/api/v1/auth/signup" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
```

Comment: Is the port mapping for mysql correct "3307:3306" ? Is the JDBC Url set accordingly ?

Comment: Relevant error: _"Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:3000"_ when using services in docker-compose, communication between those services must happen with the hostname specified in the docker-compose file, not with localhost. That is `authentication-authorization-service.uri` should be set to `http://authentication-authorization-service:300`, not to `http://localhost:3000` and same for your other services.